# CMake library directory conflict warning and error

Tags: software-installation, compiling, cmake

I am a beginner Ubuntu user trying to install the free RDP software. I am following the suggested compilation steps ([FreeRDP site](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation)). First, I cloned the repository and installed the base dependencies without problems. However, when executing cmake:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DWITH_SSE2=ON .
```

I am getting this warning:

```
CMake Warning at client/common/CMakeLists.txt:58 (add_library):
Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target freerdp-client
because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
directories:

runtime library [libgstreamer-1.0.so.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib
runtime library [libgstbase-1.0.so.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib
runtime library [libgstapp-1.0.so.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib
runtime library [libgstvideo-1.0.so.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib



 Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/anymyos/FreeRDP
```

If I ignore the warning and continue with 'make' I am getting the following error at the end:

```
[ 96%] Linking C executable generate_argument_docbook
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpcre.so.1, needed by 
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_exec'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_study'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_dfa_exec'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_fullinfo'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_get_stringnumber'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_compile2'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_get_stringtable_entries'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_free'
//home/anymyos/anaconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `pcre_config'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
client/X11/CMakeFiles/generate_argument_docbook.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'client/X11/generate_argument_docbook' failed
make[2]: *** [client/X11/generate_argument_docbook] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3514: recipe for target 'client/X11/CMakeFiles/generate_argument_docbook.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [client/X11/CMakeFiles/generate_argument_docbook.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed Anaconda Python in the past and it seems that this error is due to a conflict with the python library directory by looking at the error (this directory was added to PATH). Any advice on how to solve it?

Comment: It's more likely to be something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` than (executable search) `PATH`

Comment: @steeldriver `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not listed when I run `printenv`, I do not think I changed anything related to it.

Comment: changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH did work for me, how to tell system install cmake to forget about anaconda completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought, the problem was Anaconda python being added as the first entry to `PATH`, removing Anaconda from `PATH` solved the issue. I did that as follows:

`export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:\
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

I found the solution [here](https://gitlab.com/morpheus.lab/morpheus/issues/3)

Comment: I just get same error (building different program). This didn't helped, but running `conda install --force-reinstall pcre` fixed the issue for me.